# Python MySQL insert NULL (None) value error

Tags: python, mysql, null

I am trying to insert a NULL value into a MySQL db int field with a python script. NOT NULL is off on the field so its not that. I have manually inserted a NULL value into database and that worked fine and my code works fine if I put a literal value in the place of None.

I have looked a several people's examples of how to do this and as far as I can tell there is nothing wrong in syntax.

Code:

```
length2 = None

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tableName(Length) VALUES(%s)", length2)
```

Error:

```
Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'%s)' at line 1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You should initialize length2 to "NULL" rather than None.

Comment: The 2nd argument to `execute()` should be a tuple (or list).  Please change to `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tableName(Length) VALUES(%s)", (length2,))` and report back.

Comment: That did it thanks! Didn't realize you need a , following first item to make it a list

Comment: * a tuple, not a list. `[length2]` is a list without commas.

Comment: Lev is correct. The comma makes it a tuple. Per this site's protocol I have posted my comment as an answer. Feel free to accept to help other users of this site more easily identify that your question was answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second argument to `execute()` should be a tuple (or list).
Please change your code to:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tableName (Length) VALUES (%s);", (length2,))
```